# Parse search int value in android studio

Tags: java, android, search, android-studio, parse-platform

I have problem in android application , I always not get the value that I want

whats my program should do ? 
first take an integer value from the user in edit text and then it will check this value in the ParseObject [PatientFile] which already saved in my database in the Parse.com and will search in column [IDcardNumber]  and then compare the value in edit text with the values in column [IDcardNumber] .

My problem : 
- first problem I don't Know how to get an integer value so I think this is one of the error 
- second problem I think my Search code is wrong because I try it with a string value and it also give me "Not successful register" 
- I don't Have any error in logcat it's only when I write the number in the text field I get "Not successful register "
- if I can search and get the equal value I waana get the objectId of this value but I don't know how ?

this is my java code :

```
package com.example.user.connectuserfile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected EditText midcard;
    protected Button mcheck;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mcheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.checkbutton);
        midcard =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.IDcard);
        //LISTEN TO REGISTER BUTTON CLICK
        mcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int sword = Integer.parseInt(midcard.getText().toString().trim());

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PatientFile");
                query.whereEqualTo("IDcardNumber", sword);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterAcitivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not Sucessful register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I really need you help 
Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. your string to integer convert is right (btw, you can check it using debug mode). 2. Can you send `midcard.getText().toString()` instead `sword` and check what's happen (using debug mode..)

Comment: @AsfK I try it and I get the same result , in debug mode I get the Number 1234567 which is the same in IDcardNumber but it doesn't search in IDcardNumber

Comment: @AsfK I get in Mtransormed = 1234567